# Recyler view lat item not seen on touch

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented recycler view in the following manner :

[image: Recycler view]

now on the click of any one of the rows, the view is expanded like this :

[image: Expanded view]

now the problem i am facing is that when i try to expand the last item of the recycler view , the view is expanded but we cannot understand as the recycler view does not scroll up. so it is expaned in real but since it is below the screen the user thinks that nothing has happened.

Like in the 1st image if we click on the last item, i.e. photograph the row is expanded but we donot understand untill we actually scroll it up like this :

[image: After scolling up]

so now how do i acheive this ? i mean if the last item on the screen is expanded how to i scroll it a bit up so the user understands the difference.

CODE :

```
      @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (holder instanceof ViewHolder)
        {
            final ViewHolder bodyholder = (ViewHolder) holder;
            if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).name.length() == 0) {
                pd = new InstaDrawer();

                bodyholder.penddoc_tv.setText(UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).DOC_NAME);

                if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).ADDININFO_FLAG.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

                bodyholder.pending_row.setId(position);
                bodyholder.pending_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //     crop(position);

                        InstaDrawer.pendingDocList= UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId());
                        UtilInsta.setPosition(con, v.getId());
                        if (bodyholder.pend_ll.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).option = false;
                            bodyholder.pend_ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (bodyholder.remarks_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).will_chek = false;
                                UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).unable_chek = false;
                            }
                        } else {

                            bodyholder.pend_ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          //  setHide(v.getId());
                            if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).ADDININFO_FLAG.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                                bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            } else {
                                bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }
                            UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).option = true;
                            if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).MIN_DOC == "Y") {
                                bodyholder.provie_later.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                bodyholder.unable_submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                        }


                        if(expandedpos>=0 && expandedpos!=v.getId())
                        {
                                int prev = expandedpos;
                                notifyItemChanged(prev);
                        }
                        expandedpos = v.getId();
                    }

                });


                //  holder.acct_name_tv.setText(pendingDocLists.get(position).CUST_NAME);
                bodyholder.camera.setId(position);
                bodyholder.camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        InstaDrawer.pendingDocList= UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId());
                        UtilInsta.setPosition(con, v.getId());
                        if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).ADDININFO_FLAG.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                            if (Util.isNetworkConnected(con))
                                DocumentInfo(0, v.getId());
                            else
                                Util.shownointernet(con);
                        }
                            else {
                            UtilInsta.setFILE_NAME(con, "");
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                                    ( con.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||  con.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){

                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(((Activity)con),
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, com.app.hdfc.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                        MyConstants.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CAM);

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                if(UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).DOC_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase("Photograph"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(con, FrontCamera.class);
                                    UtilInsta.CUST_NO = UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).CUST_NO;
                                            (con).startActivity(intent);
                                    ((Activity)con).finish();
                                }else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(con, CroppingActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("camera_gallery", 0);
                                    intent.putExtra("fromRecycler", true);
                                    intent.putExtra("position", v.getId());
                                    intent.putExtra("DOC_NAME", UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).DOC_NAME);
                                    UtilInsta.doc_name = UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).DOC_NAME;
                                    Log.d("Recycler", UtilInsta.doc_name);
                                    intent.putExtra("CUST_NO", UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).CUST_NO);
                                    (con).startActivity(intent);
                                    ((Activity) con).finish();
                                }

                            }

                        }


                    }
                });
                bodyholder.gallery.setId(position);
                bodyholder.gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        InstaDrawer.pendingDocList= UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId());
                        UtilInsta.setPosition(con, v.getId());
                        if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).ADDININFO_FLAG.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                            if(Util.isNetworkConnected(con))
                            DocumentInfo(1, v.getId());
                            else
                            Util.shownointernet(con);
                        else {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                                    con.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(((Activity)con),
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        MyConstants.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);

                            }
                            else {
                                UtilInsta.setFILE_NAME(con, "");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(con, CroppingActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("camera_gallery", 1);
                                intent.putExtra("fromRecycler", true);
                                intent.putExtra("position", v.getId());
                                intent.putExtra("DOC_NAME", UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).DOC_NAME);
                                UtilInsta.doc_name = UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).DOC_NAME;
                                Log.d("Recycler", UtilInsta.doc_name);

                                intent.putExtra("CUST_NO", UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).CUST_NO);
                                (con).startActivity(intent);
                                ((Activity) con).finish();
                            }
                        }


                    }
                });

                if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).MIN_DOC.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    bodyholder.provie_later.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bodyholder.unable_submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else {
                    bodyholder.provie_later.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bodyholder.unable_submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                bodyholder.provie_later.setId(position);
                bodyholder.provie_later.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (remark == 1) {
                            remark = 0;
                            bodyholder.provie_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle1);
                            bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).will_chek = false;
                        } else if (remark == 0 || remark == 2) {
                            bodyholder.unable_submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
                            bodyholder.provie_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle1_hover);
                            remark = 1;
                            bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).will_chek = true;
                        }
                    }
                });


                bodyholder.unable_submit.setId(position);
                bodyholder.unable_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (remark == 2) {
                            remark = 0;
                            bodyholder.unable_submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
                            bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).unable_chek = false;
                        } else if (remark == 0 || remark == 1) {
                            bodyholder.provie_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle1);
                            bodyholder.unable_submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2_hover);
                            remark = 2;
                            bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(v.getId()).unable_chek = true;
                        }
                    }
                });

                bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setId(position);
                bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (Util.isNetworkConnected(con))
                            DocumentInfo(2, v.getId()); // 2 for kyc list
                        else
                            Util.shownointernet(con);
                    }
                });

                bodyholder.remarks_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String remark_str = bodyholder.remarks_edittext.getText().toString().trim();
                        if (remark_str.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(con, "Please enter some remark", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else if (remark_str.length() > 100) {
                            Toast.makeText(con, "Please enter remark less than 100 characters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {


                            //Toast.makeText(con, "Remark : " + remark + " Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            String remarktype = "";
                            if (remark == 1) {
                                remarktype = "PROVIDE_LATER";
                            } else if (remark == 2) {
                                remarktype = "NOT_AVAILABLE";
                            }
                            Log.e("Remarktype", remarktype + "1 " + remark);

                            if(Util.isNetworkConnected(con)) {
                                uploddoc(remarktype, remark_str);
                                bodyholder.remarks_edittext.setText("");
                            }
                            else
                            Util.shownointernet(con);

                            bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            bodyholder.pend_ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).option = false;
                            bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });

//                if (!UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).REMARKS.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
//                    bodyholder.remarks_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                        bodyholder.remarks_tv.setText("*Remark - " + UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).REMARKS);

                if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).STATUS.equalsIgnoreCase("NOT_AVAILABLE")) {
                    bodyholder.remarks_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bodyholder.remarks_tv.setText("*Remark - " + UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).REMARKS);
                    bodyholder.unable_submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2_hover);
                    bodyholder.provie_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle1);
                    bodyholder.remarks_edittext.setText(UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).REMARKS);
                    UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).unable_chek =true;
                } else if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).STATUS.equalsIgnoreCase("PROVIDE_LATER")) {
                    bodyholder.remarks_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bodyholder.remarks_tv.setText("*Remark - " + UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).REMARKS);
                    bodyholder.unable_submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
                    bodyholder.provie_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle1_hover);
                    bodyholder.remarks_edittext.setText(UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).REMARKS);
                    UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).will_chek =true;
                }
                     else {
                        bodyholder.remarks_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bodyholder.unable_submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
                    bodyholder.provie_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle1);
                    bodyholder.remarks_edittext.setText("");
                        }

                bodyholder.pending_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bodyholder.acct_name_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);




                if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).unable_chek) {
                    bodyholder.provie_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle1);
                    bodyholder.unable_submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2_hover);

                    bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).unable_chek = true;
                } else {

                    bodyholder.unable_submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
                    bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).unable_chek = false;
                }

                if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).will_chek) {
                    bodyholder.unable_submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
                    bodyholder.provie_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle1_hover);

                    bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).will_chek = true;
                } else {

                    bodyholder.provie_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle1);
                    bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).will_chek = false;
                }

                if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).option) {
                    bodyholder.pend_ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).ADDININFO_FLAG.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                        bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } else {
                        bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).option = true;
                    if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).MIN_DOC == "Y") {
                        bodyholder.provie_later.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        bodyholder.unable_submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else {
                    bodyholder.pend_ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (bodyholder.remarks_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        bodyholder.remarks_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).will_chek = false;
                        UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).unable_chek = false;
                    }

                }

            } else if (UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).name.length() > 0) {
                bodyholder.pending_row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bodyholder.acct_name_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bodyholder.acct_name_tv.setText(UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).name);
                //continue comeback;
            }

            if(expandedpos == position)
            {
                bodyholder.pend_ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(UtilInsta.PendingDoc.get(position).option)
                bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }else
            {
                bodyholder.pend_ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                bodyholder.tv_clickforkyc.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

    }else if (holder instanceof FooterViewHoldrer){
            FooterViewHoldrer footerViewHoldrer = (FooterViewHoldrer) holder;
            if(UtilInsta.PendingDoc.size()==0)
            {
                footerViewHoldrer.empty_pendingdoc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                footerViewHoldrer.pending_continue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        footerViewHoldrer.loan_sanctioned.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            else
            {
                footerViewHoldrer.empty_pendingdoc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                footerViewHoldrer.pending_continue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                footerViewHoldrer.loan_sanctioned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if(submit_activate)
            {
                footerViewHoldrer.pending_continue.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_button);
            }else
            {
                footerViewHoldrer.pending_continue.setBackgroundResource(R.color.myblack);
            }
            footerViewHoldrer.pending_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(submit_activate) {
//                        Toast.makeText(con,"Button Activated.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(Util.isNetworkConnected(con))
                       new UpdateStep().execute();
                        else
                            Util.shownointernet(con);

                    }else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(con,"Submit/Remark all Documents",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            });


        }

    }
```

Comment: have you used expandable `listview/recyleview` ? If yes then please put that code with question

Comment: no i havnt used expandable listview, normal recycler view

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
yourRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

the variable `position` will be having the value of the expanded position.

Comment: the touch is in adapter, how do i add scrolltoposition in adapter?

Comment: pass the RecyclerView in the constructor of Your adapter. You better post the code of adapter.

Comment: added the code, and i removed the scroll property of recycler view and cz it is inside a scrllview

Comment: I want the constructor of your recycleview adapter.